# Can one instruct LuaLaTeX to use T2A encoded fonts?

Tags: fonts, luatex, cyrillic

As it is stated in answer to [Can XeTeX | LuaTeX use MetaFont fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31625/can-xetex-luatex-use-metafont-fonts), LuaLaTeX can use MetaFont fonts. **If so, how can one instruct LuaLaTeX to use T2A encoded fonts  (e.g. cm-super)  to typeset cyrillic text?** I used to think that LuaLaTeX can use only those  fonts which are internally encoded accoding to Unicode. Am I right?

**UPDATE:**
The following code (slightly modifed from @Leo Liu's answer) prints "Б-Б-Б" if it is compiled by pdflatex but "Б--Б" in case of lualatex:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % cyrillic font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % source file encoding
\begin{document}
\symbol{"C1}-Б-\CYRB
\end{document}
```

I wonder why `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` does not work for lualatex. I tried also `luainputenc` with same result. Note that `\CYRB` command is defined by `fontenc` which loads `t2aenc.def`. As to `inputenc` it should match unicode chars in source file to corresponding `\cyr...` macros. And it did so for `pdflatex` but not `lualatex`.

Comment: Note that `inputenc` does not support luatex (nor xetex) as the author(s) refuse to added support for new engines. But there is `luainputenc` if you really need that stuff.

Comment: @KhaledHosny, I substituted `inputenc` with `luainputenc` but did not reach desired result.

Comment: It does here, I get `Б-Б-Б`, but to be honest, I never used that stuff, but `luainputenc` documentation is a good start to get an overall idea of the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use it directly. `fontenc` works well with XeTeX/LuaTeX. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\symbol{"C1} % produce Б

\end{document}
```

However, you can't use it with `fontspec`. A error will be produced:

```
! Corrupted NFSS tables.
```

Moreover, it is a problem to input Cyrillic text. `inputenc` cannot be used in XeTeX and LuaTeX directly.

Anyway, if you want to use Cyrillic text in XeLaTeX and LuaTeX, just use [CM Unicode fonts](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/cm-unicode). For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}

Русский язык

\textsf{Русский язык}

\texttt{Русский язык}

\end{document}
```

---

### Additional notes:

`inputenc` is used for text of 8 bits encodings. Knuth's tradational TeX can use ASCII (0x00--0x7F) only. Later TeX implementations can process 8 bits extended ASCII (0x00--0xFF).

Most western encodings are some types of extended ASCII, e.g. Latin 1 (ISO 8859-1), KOI8-R, CP866. The ASCII part are identical, but higher codes (0x80--0xFF) are different.

Fonts has there own encodings. Basically, a font encoding corresponds with a input encoding. For example, `T1` encoding is very similar to Latin 1 encoding, and `T2A` is very similar to Code Page 1251 in Windows. That is to say, if you TeX a source file of CP1251, and use `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}`, you will get proper Russian text without any other packages.

`inputenc` makes us to input text with different encodings, but use fonts of only one font encoding. When you choose `utf8x` option, and use `T2A` font encoding, then the characters are mapped to `T2A` (`CP1251`) from UTF-8 inputs. That's what `inputenc` do.

How `inputenc` works? It makes the characters active (catcode 13), and do the mapping. For multibyte characters, things may be more complex.

Why `inputenc` cannot be used in XeTeX and LuaTeX? XeTeX and LuaTeX use UTF-8 encoding for input. A multibyte Unicode character in XeTeX/LuaTeX is only *one* character, but in pdfTeX it's two or three. Thus the different TeX engines sees the input stream differently. `inputenc` fails in XeTeX and LuaTeX.

I'm not very familar with LuaTeX. In XeTeX, there is a special mode for compatibility. You can use `\XeTeXinputencoding` to change the input encoding temporarily, and the `"bytes"` encoding makes XeTeX works like a 8 bit TeX engine. Thus, this works for XeTeX:

```
\XeTeXinputencoding "bytes"
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

Русский язык

\textsf{Русский язык}

\texttt{Русский язык}

\end{document}
```

(This technique is used by obsolete `xCJK` package.)

However, `inputenc` may cause real Unicode fonts with `fontspec` works unusually. It is still not a good idea to use it.

---

### By Khaled Hosny

`luainputenc` can be used here. I didn't know that.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[lutf8x]{luainputenc}


\begin{document}

Русский язык

\textsf{Русский язык}

\texttt{Русский язык}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I asked. If you type "Б" from keybord, you will get no output: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
"Б" produce nothing 
\end{document}`

Comment: @Igor: LuaTeX is a UTF-8 only engine, and Leo has said that you can't use `inputenc` with it. Can you explain what is wrong with the standard approach of loading a proper Unicode font?

Comment: @Igor: You are still confusing what the engine can do with what is convenient for the user.  LuaTeX can certainly load MetaFont fonts, which you can happily do with the `\font` primitive. However, they simply don't map correctly to UTF-8 input, and so there is a lot of 'behind the scenes' work in the `inputenc` package to convert from a UTF-8 sequence into something that 8-bit pdfTeX can display. So if you want to use an 8-bit encoded font with LuaTeX, you will have to use macro-based input to access the glyphs outside of the 8-bit range.

Comment: @Igor: The key point is that LuaTeX is fundamentally a UTF-8 engine, so for _direct_ use of UTF-8 characters in the input you need a font that includes the appropriately-placed glyph. If you want to use an 8-bit font, then you have to accept other input forms. That is fine, for example, if you want the 'dangerous end' character that Knuth used in _The TeXbook_, as it's a one-off, but for general UTF-8 input _use a modern font_.

Comment: @JosephWright: nothing wrong with `fontspec` (which loads unicode fonts). My question (Can XeTeX | LuaTeX use MetaFont fonts?) was about MF fonts with 8-bit encodings. I see from transcript of compilation that lualatex indeed loads .pk bitmap fonts. Hence, it can use MF fotns. The problem is to learn how to get `inputenc` package working.

Comment: @JosephWright, sorry for molestation. I am testing new version of babel's russian.ldf in even unlikely environments in order to issue appropiate PackageWarning.

Comment: @Igor: See my comments [in the chat system](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)